# A simple Cartesian plane for X and Y coordinates and the origin point being at the center

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have written the following code in order for the coordinates of users' mouse clicks to be displayed from the center of an image ( that I upload else where in the code ).

```
    $( document ).ready( function(e)
    {
        $( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e)
        {
            var coordX = ( e.pageX - $( this ).offset().left - ( $( this ).width()  * 0.5 ) );
            var coordY = ( e.pageY - $( this ).offset().top  - ( $( this ).height() * 0.5 ) );
            alert( coordX.toFixed(1) + ' , ' + coordY.toFixed(1) );
        });
    });
```

But unlike a regular 2D plane for coordinates' origin, when I click somewhere in the first quarter that has positive X and Y, I still get one of them as negative.

How can I modify this code snippet to make it resemble a normal Cartesian plane for X and Y coordinates and the origin point being at the center?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/V3xUV/

```
$( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e)
{
    var coordX = ( e.pageX - $( this ).offset().left - ( $( this ).width()  * 0.5 ));
    var coordY = -( e.pageY - $( this ).offset().top  - ( $( this ).height() * 0.5 ));
    alert( coordX.toFixed(1) + ' , ' + coordY.toFixed(1) );
});
```

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. Another quick question: As you noticed, I "round up" the results, but I still get one fraction digit. Is there a function that rounds up the results to an integer? Cheers

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks. Do you always reply to questions with the same tags as my question? I really appreciate your help...

Comment: Glad to read it :) if my comment help you then +1 so it will be highlighted to other reader with similar problem. I'm more into .NET MVC but I like to help practical HTML/CSS/JS problems. At the end, I'll be happy to help you again if I can!

Comment: Sure, I have "accepted" and highlighted "useful" your answer and comments. I am also developing something in MVS2010 in C++ so I will shortly be having some question there too! Cheers very much,

Comment: Best luck for your projects! Have a nice day